# How to give marker a z-index wild-googlemaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

Probably impossible without using an API, but I'm going to ask anyway because it would save me so much pain and tears.

***Is there a way to give a googlemaps marker a z-index without using the API?*** I've got the plug-in called Wild-Googlemaps implemented on my wordpress site. And I've created a googlemaps div, with an overlaying div set to opacity:0.7 for styling purposes.

Now I've lost the ability to click the marker, so I need to somehow change its z-index.

Anyone had this problem or has any ideas? Much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that without accessing API.

By default all markers are created as a part of a map canvas and you cannot access them (they don't belong to the DOM tree). You could do that after turning off `optimized` parameter passed during creation of the marker (take a look at 
description of [marker parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)), but this require access to API.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for the help.